# What library can you recommend to capture image from a webcam in .Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

What library can you recommend to capture image from a webcam in .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Image Acquisition does the trick with [wiaCommandTakePicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630806.aspx) (VB.NET as per your tag :) )

as demonstrated in this [project by Hanselman in coding4fun](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912546.aspx)

I pasted the C# code, but you can read the VB.NET alternatives on the site also:

```
CommonDialogClass class1 = new CommonDialogClass();
Device d = class1.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, true,false);
if (d != null)
{
    settings.DeviceID = d.DeviceID;
    settings.Save();
}


Item item = device.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);
foreach (string format in item.Formats)
{
    if (format == jpegGuid)
    {
        WIA.ImageFile imagefile = item.Transfer(format) as WIA.ImageFile;
        filename = GetFreeFileName();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) == false)
        {
            imagefile.SaveFile(filename);
        }
        this.picLastImage.Load(filename);
        return filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls correct links they are not working

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630827(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

DirectShow is pretty good. Look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/c-streaming-webcam-video)