# Using a webcam in a vb.net winform project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am new to vb.net and I am relatively new to programming in general. I am creating a windows form project in vb.net which uses a webcam to take a photo of a person. The photo is subsequently saved to a database. I won't have any problem saving it to the database but I haven't a clue where to start with using a webcam with vb.net. I know this question has been asked before and I have been doing a lot of looking around the internet for a solution I can understand but I am finding this very difficult. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What library can you recommend to capture image from a webcam in .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509975/what-library-can-you-recommend-to-capture-image-from-a-webcam-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was given the following link on 'Code Project' that solved my problem.
Link:
http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EasyWebCam/WinFormVBWebCam/Form1.vb

Comment: This is not a good fit for the StackOverflow Q&A: for instance, see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for more information. The summary: answers should contain at least some actual information, and should not be link-only.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex library than EasyWebCam that can do great things with webcams is AForge.NET.  If you find yourself having a need for more advanced features, such as zoom control, I'd recommend checking it out.
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/