# how to control camera through Asp.net sessions and application programming architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

how to control camera through Asp.net sessions and Asp.net application programming architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about a camera attached to the server or to the client ? 
You can't control a camera on the client with plain ASP .NET. It is a server-side technology.

You need to write some code that runs on the client - a way to do this would be to control the Webcam with [Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx). This might be a good fit for yoyr application.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the camera.

Mostly likely you mean a user's web cam.  This is just not possible without a plugin like flash, silverlight, or activex.  Remember that asp.net still boils down to sending html and javascript to the browser.  Your c#/vb server code never goes anywhere near the user's computer, and therefore never anywhere near their web cam.  There's no connection to the camera from javascript, either.  You have to use a browser plug in.

On the off chance you mean something like a traffic cam or public camera attached to the server that you allow users to control or view, you should look at this other question on how to use a camera from .Net:
[How can I stream webcam video with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c)