# Streaming video over with C#

Tags: c#, video-streaming

Greeting

Is there any example code to show how to stream video over ip C# windows app???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Comment: @NAVEED Thank you for your, I'm looking to stream a video file like flv not live stream. any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/cameraviewer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.fathsoft.com/videocapx.html. VideoCapX ActiveX control supports streaming live and file-based video over IP. There are several C# samples included.