# saving avi on server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I built an application that used to record the clients screen in an avi file. Now the client wants to save the recoding on web server in real time. i.e he want that all recording should be saved directly on web server, how can we do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be "real time"?  If all you are doing is saving it (for archiving, for example), you do not need to stream the file.

Comment: the architecture is like we have a presenter , server, end user. the presenter screen is needed to be displayed to the end user... this is the task

Comment: So you want to build something like goto meeting, with the server also recording an .avi file?

Comment: Maybe check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Comment: yes... just like webex... i only need to allow the end user to see the client's screen...