# how can i get stream of webcam? and send it to other side

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, webcam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stream webcam video with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c)

my question is how to get web cam stream in .net c# 
Can I get it as data and store it to buffer and send it to other side.

Please give me some idea

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Silverlight 4 look at [Capturing the Webcam in Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)

Comment: no i have to do it only with .net c#

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial here using avicap32.dll:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/810262008070218AM/8.aspx

Unfortunately saving every frame is probably not the best solution but you can buffer it.