# record video and sound and save that using web-cam in c#

Tags: c#, .net, video-capture

I want to develop video recording + sound using web-cam and store the file in my server.  ( No silverlight )

Please guide me how to do that, I try with some third party control and also try some my logic but no success.

PLease help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: AForge.net...Jquery webcam plugin....and many more solutions available online

Comment: search before asking pal, here is the answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Comment: @Abhishek are you sure that AForge.net can record sound while recording a video?

Comment: @cmario no, it can't

Answer (score 0):

For recording Live video streaming and to store audio streaming from your web page you can use Flash then for storing the stream you can use Red5 server http://www.red5.org/.
Through Flash you can access the web camera connected to your machine to save the video or audio streams to the server.

If you want more details i can help as i have implemented this several times in my project

here is the sample code for the video streaming using web cam to your red5 server

You can connect to the server using the following :

```
    _connection = new NetConnection();
    _connection.client = { onBWDone: function():void{ /*Alert.show('onBWDone', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK); */} };
    _connection.objectEncoding = flash.net.ObjectEncoding.AMF0;

    _connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
    _connection.connect("your server name like rtmp://yourhost/oflaDemo");
```

After connecting to the server  you can attach the camera to your flash and save the stream to your red5 server.

```
        _camera = Camera.getCamera();
        _camera.setMode(320,240,10000);
        _camera.setQuality(0,85);
        _video = new Video();
        _video.x=0;
        _video.y=0;
        _video.height= _height;
        _video.width = _width;
        _video.attachCamera(_camera);
        uiComp.addChild(_video);
        _stream = new NetStream(_connection);
        _stream.attachCamera(_camera);
        _stream.publish(_streamName,"live");
```

You can use live,record or publish while publishing the stream to the server.For more example you can refer the Adobe docs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/

Comment: yeah sure.....
please tell me the way with which i can integrate it with my application.

Comment: you can create flash files using flex then embedd that to your web page for showing the webcam

Comment: can you provide me a sample file of the same....i am not familiar with flex coding

Comment: ok give me your email id ,i will send you my sample projects for video and audio streaming to red5 server

Comment: since the edits will be too long ,i will be sending the sample code to your email id

Comment: you can check editted answer for further assistance ,i have added the code