# How to stream multimedia files using C# and ASP.NET in P2P manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, real-time, p2p

so what I want to do is build up a custom web player that should have the facility to allow any user to select a file from his local hard disk and the play that, so that some other person can view it in real time, just like doing a video chat, but instead of a webcam, there would be a video clip that is being streamed.

so far, what I've come across is Microsoft's SmoothStreaming Framework, but it did not help much. Please help.
Regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c

Answer (score 0):

See following posts, hopefully it might be helpful.

- [Streaming with Windows Media Services and ASP.NET](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Techniques/Streaming-with-Windows-Media-Services-and-ASPNET/)
- [Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hey, I am not sure about MMPPF that whether it supports streaming thru any video file by just browsing into the file system and then selecting it and then putting it on the playback stream. Do you know of any such modification that I can do in it?

Comment: it's the MediaSource that I am talking about which has confused me.