# stream video to web site asp.net

Tags: asp.net, streaming-video

I have some stream of avi frames or images. How display this stream on my web site using asp.net and c#.As I now, I must have server that will create stream and send it to web site.How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please See Link which is given below

[How can I stream webcam video with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c#)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7637/DirectX-Video-Stream-and-frame-capture