# Streaming webcam from c# Windows Form to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, streaming, webcam

After some research, I cannot figure out a way which convince me to do the following.

I have a webcam, connected to a PC, and I want to Stream its content to a ASP.NET webpage hosted by azure using a Windows Form application.

Could someone help? Maybe using Expression encoder 4, I have no idea

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342774/how-can-i-stream-webcam-video-with-c?rq=1

Comment: I've already read this topic but DirectShow is actually not supported...